# Removing duplicate strlen items from array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Is this the simplest way there is for getting rid of duplicate strlen items from an array?
I do alot of programming that do similar tasks as this, thats why Im asking, if Im doing it too complicated, or if this is the easiest way.

```
$usedlength = array();
$no_duplicate_filesizes_in_here = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    foreach ($usedlength as $length) {
        if (strlen($file) == $length) continue 2;
    }
    $usedlength[] = strlen($file);
    $no_duplicate_filesizes_in_here[] = $file;
}
$files = $no_duplicate_filesizes_in_here;
```

Comment: Possibly a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is there a reason why all your files are seemingly loaded as strings, it might be a better idea to use the method `filesize`? or by *file size* do you mean the length of the file name?

Comment: its images loaded into array by file_get_contents.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. It still may be quicker to work using `filesize` first (to limit the images you eventually load as strings), but that would depend on exactly what you are trying to code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not a lot *hugely* wrong with looping manually, though your example could be:

```
$files = array_intersect_key($files, array_unique(array_map('strlen', $files)));
```

PHP has a plethora of useful [array functions](http://php.net/ref.array) available.

Comment: Nice, but keep in mind that the keys from this are different. If you want the keys to be sequential, you'll need to wrap it in array_values().

Comment: @minboost and deliberately so, if one is interested in the keys then it is generally the original keys that are wanted. The OP doesn't mention caring about keys one way or the other.

Comment: @salathe based on the original code, the original keys are not wanted. I get that it probably doesn't matter, but whenever I refactor code I make sure the final result is the same, or else I make a note that it isn't.

Comment: @minboost, there was a deliberate (if subtle) word choice where I said "your example could be". If my example was exactly replicating the OP's, I would have said so. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$no_duplicate_filesizes_in_here = array();
for ($i=count($files)-1;$i>=0;$i--){
  $no_duplicate_filesizes_in_here[strlen($files[$i])] = $file;
}
$files = array_values($no_duplicate_filesizes_in_here);
// if you don't care about the keys, don't bother with array_values()
```

Comment: I meant count(), not len(), but anyway. It's only calculating once, since it's only assigned to i once. I use the for(i) iterator so I can look thru the array backwards, so the final results match the original code. The performance difference between this for(i) and foreach() is almost always negligible - the real performance problem is looping more times than you have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.3 or above, [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) provides a nice syntax for doing this:

```
$nodupes = array_filter($files, function($file) use (&$lengths) {
    if (in_array(strlen($file), (array) $lengths)) {
        return false;
    }

    $lengths[] = strlen($file);
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as short as some other answers, but another aproach would be to use a key-based lookup:

```
$used = array();
$no_dupes = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if ( !array_key_exists(($length = strlen($file)), $used) ) {
    $used[$length] = true;
    $no_dupes[] = $file;
  }
}
```

This would have the added bonus of not wasting time on storing duplicates (only to overwrite them later), however, whether this loop would be faster than some of PHP's built in array methods is probably down to a number of factors (number of duplicates, length of `files` array and so on) and would need to be tested. The above is what I would assume to be quicker in most cases, but I'm not a processor ;)

The above also means the first file found is the one that is kept, rather than the last found in some of the other approaches.